# Database (Ef) connection from Azure Function

Tags: azure, entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

So I have an Azure function app from there I want to connect to database. I am using dependency injection for this and creating service but I am not able to connect to db. I will show some of my code.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
                .ConfigureServices(s =>
                {
                    s.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(o =>
                        o.UseSqlServer("database_connection"));
                   
                })
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }

    }
```

This is the code in my Azure Function project. Here are the packages for my function project

```
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="4.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.3.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.6.0" />
```

Now I have another project, my data layer, where I have my MyDbContext. Here is the code for this

```
public partial class MyDbContext: DbContext
    {
        public static String connString = null;

        public MyDbContext() { }

        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
            var opt = options.FindExtension<SqlServerOptionsExtension>();
            connString = opt.ConnectionString;

        }

        public static MyDbContextGetNewInstance()
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>();
            optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connString);
            return new MyDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
}
```

I have the same code from my api project and there the connection with database works fine. But from my azure function it does not. What I have experienced is that if I put a break point in the constructor from my azure function, it does not gets called and that is my connString is null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: refer this article https://azurelessons.com/azure-functions-database-connection/#:~:text=1%20Log%20in%20to%20the%20Azure%20Portal%202,Connection%20String%20to%20add%20the%20database%20connection%20string.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something?

Yes, try to remove your default constructor from `MyDbContext`.

Use the below sample and working code to connect the `azure function` to database using `EF`.

**Step 1:-** In `Startup` file use below code.

```cs
using FunctionApp_Connect_db_context_azure_functions;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(StartUp))]
namespace FunctionApp_inject_2_db_context_azure_functions_72552798
{
    public class StartUp : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer("Server=tcp:xxx;User ID=adminserverdb1;Password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"));

            builder.Services.AddOptions();
        }
    }
}
```

**Setp 2 :-** Add `DB context` file and use below code

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunctionApp_Connect_db_context_azure_functions
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
            this.ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Persons1> Persons1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Step 3 :-** Create `Azure function` and use below code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp_Connect_db_context_azure_functions
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly MyDbContext _myDbcontext;
        
        public Function1(MyDbContext mydbcontext)
        {
            this._myDbcontext = mydbcontext;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("*/5 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            var querydb = await _myDbcontext .Persons2.ToListAsync(); ; // Returns count 1
            
            log.LogInformation("First Db table data :- First Name :- "+ querydb[0].FirstName.ToString()+" ,Address :- "+ querydbone[0].Address.ToString());
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Database** [image]

**Output**

[image]